# Sub-content isn't scaling with background CSS

Tags: html, css, containers, scale, padding

I'm creating a Timetable which contains specific activities within a list of days from Mon-Sun. Here's the example:

https://lylak.uk/test/

All of them look great, except for when you go to 'Saturday' because there's more content so it requires another line. The background isn't scaling with the additional content, so now it's being pushed into the other section. What I want is for the background to scale with the additional pages when going to the 'Saturday' link. So comparing with the 'Tuesday' section, I've added an additional few sections for 'program program-schedule'

The current code is:

```
    <div id="fh5co-schedule-section" class="fh5co-lightgray-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="heading-section text-center animate-box">
                        <h2>Class Timetable</h2>
                        <p>The Fitness Centre is always open during class times.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row animate-box">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
                    <ul class="schedule">
                        <li><a href="#" class="active" data-sched="tuesday">Tuesday</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-sched="saturday">Saturday</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">

                    <div class="col-md-12 schedule-container">



                        <div class="schedule-content active" data-day="tuesday">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-dumbell.svg" alt="Cycling">
                                    <small>4:30PM - 5:30PM</small>
                                    <h3>Kidzone Kickboxing</h3>
                                    <span>John Doe</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-yoga.svg" alt="">
                                    <small>5PM - 6PM</small>
                                    <h3>Capoeira<br>(Brazilian Martial Art)</h3>
                                    <span>James Smith</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-cycling.svg" alt="">
                                    <small>6PM - 7PM</small>
                                    <h3>Adult Kick Boxing</h3>
                                    <span>Rita Doe</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-boxing.svg" alt="Cycling">
                                    <small>8PM - 9PM</small>
                                    <h3>Boxing Workout</h3>
                                    <span>John Dose</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- END sched-content -->



                        <div class="schedule-content" data-day="saturday">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-dumbell.svg" alt="Cycling">
                                    <small>8AM - 9:15AM</small>
                                    <h3>Enshin Karate</h3>
                                    <span>John Doe</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-yoga.svg" alt="">
                                    <small>9:15AM - 10:45AM</small>
                                    <h3>Traditional Jiu jitsu</h3>
                                    <span>James Smith</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-cycling.svg" alt="">
                                    <small>10:45AM - 11:45AM</small>
                                    <h3>Kidzone Boxing</h3>
                                    <span>Rita Doe</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-boxing.svg" alt="Cycling">
                                    <small>12PM - 1PM</small>
                                    <h3>Kidzone kickboxing (beginners)</h3>
                                    <span>John Dose</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-boxing.svg" alt="Cycling">
                                    <small>1PM - 2PM</small>
                                    <h3>Intermediate kickboxing</h3>
                                    <span>John Dose</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="program program-schedule">
                                    <img src="images/fit-boxing.svg" alt="Cycling">
                                    <small>2:15PM - 3:15PM</small>
                                    <h3>Kidzone Mixed Martial Arts<br>(5-12 years)</h3>
                                    <span>John Dose</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END sched-content -->


                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#fh5co-programs-section,
#fh5co-schedule-section,
#fh5co-team-section,
#fh5co-blog-section,
#fh5co-contact {
  padding: 7em 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #fh5co-programs-section,
  #fh5co-schedule-section,
  #fh5co-team-section,
  #fh5co-blog-section,
  #fh5co-contact {
    padding: 4em 0;
  }
}

.schedule {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.schedule li {
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.schedule li a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.schedule li a:active, .schedule li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.schedule li a.active {
  background: #4CB648;
  color: #fff !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .schedule li {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.schedule-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.schedule-content.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

I've been playing with this ages with no luck. This is a template that I've downloaded. I've found that the section that causes the main background size is:

```
#fh5co-schedule-section,
  padding: 7em 0;
  background-color: grey;
```

When I change the padding to 20em for example, then it fits all the content. But then the other days where it's only 1 line, it's far too big.

I've tried putting the 'saturday' section within it's own container, replicate the code for the primary container into a separate section for 'saturday', create it's own "div id". Or things such as:

```
<div class="schedule-content-saturday" data-day="saturday">

#fh5co-schedule-section-saturday {
  padding: 20em 0;
}
```

But none of the above seem to work. Maybe it's because the entire section as a whole is padded, whereas I'm attempting to try and pad the specific container for Saturday, as I don't want the entire section to scale, just for the Saturday button.

Do I need to convert each day to it's own separate container, or is there a way for me to scale the sub-container with the background? Thanks.

You can download the site files here:

https://lylak.uk/test/test.zip

Comment: you should find an alternative to absolute position, the issue is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for:

- remove the height in px on the container, make it height: auto; I guess it is set by JS? Remove that code.

  .schedule-container {
      height: auto;
  }
- then make the rows css

  ```
  .schedule-content {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      opacity: 0;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
      -o-transition: 0.3s;
      transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .schedule-content.active {
      opacity: 1;
      height: auto;
      visibility: visible;
      overflow: visible;
  }
  ```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much :)